# Problem with source of my JAVA Project- Can not upload it to Eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse, netbeans

I have a basic but important question. 
Our client has an application that has been written with JAVA. We need to modify something in one of the classes. 
They passed us the Source files of this project, but I really have doubt that if they sent us the source or no!
This is the structure of zip file:

[image]

But when I import it to Eclipse (Import Existing Project to workspace) I see the error that is saying: "No projects are found to import"

How can I be sure if they sent us the source?

Actually I want to be sure and then ask them...

I tried also to open it with Apache Netbeans but it says "No Netbeans projects added".

Can anyone help me about this?

Thanks
Sep

Comment: Maybe try to import it as an ant project...

Comment: Also, make sure to extract the project before importing it.

Comment: That just means it is probably just the source files and does not contain the Eclipse or Netbeans project definition files. Create a new Java project yourself and then Import the files in to that.

Comment: Hi greg, I tried it also.. you are right, project seems does not contain Eclipse definiton files... 
I Tried to create a JavaProject,but dont know how to add these files to my project?

Comment: As I already said, `build.xml` seems like ant. Try to import it as an **ant project** or create a new java project and copy the source files to the `src` directory.

Comment: Hi dan1st, I cant see ant project in my imports options... maybe I need to install some extensions??

Comment: 'File > Import > General > File System' will import whatever it finds in to a project, this may or may not make sense.

Comment: Hi Greg, I can Import it in this way but I can not open and modify my .class files, i see the error "The class file is not on the classpath" . I need to modify just some string from one of these classes and then Export it as "Runable as JAR file". But I can not do it because I need to run my Main.Class as a Java Runtime (since I can not see Main.java)!

Comment: You will have to set up the Java Build Path to specify the correct folders in the project properties. But note that .class files are compiled code which you can't easily modify, you need the .java source files for that.

Comment: How can I have this .java instead of .class? if I Import the projects in the way you mentioned, I can not see it as .JAVA .... Means that I do not import in a right way or I do not have the complete source of the project?

Comment: Well look through the zip file and see if there are any .java files anywhere. If you can't find any then you don't have the actual source, it is probably just the compiled production code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The complete build structure does not look like a default gradle/maven or even Eclipse/Netbeans IDE style (as mentioned already by greg-449)

### Howto import plain sources into Eclipse - without maven or gradle

Normally a eclipse project setup looks like

```
/.project
/.classpath
/src/java
     Hello.java
/test/java
     HelloTest.java
/bin
     Hello.class
     HelloTest.class
```

So I would do following

1. **Create a new Java Project** in eclipse and use as customized project location your root folder of your source files.
2. When asked for source folder location you can either use `/src/java` (when you
   you are free to restructure the files), or **add all folders where
   sources are located** (e.g.maybe `nbproject` contains sources ?) **as source 
   folders of the project**.
3. Libraries: If the project contains dependencies and you want no compile failures, you must add all libraries to your eclipse project. When you can start the (ant ?) build you will have all libraries inside build folder. Add those to your eclipse project at the build path properties.
4. After project creation + build in eclipse, the files `.project` and `.classpath` are created. Inside the project you should now see at least your sources inside java source folders - and maybe you are able to start the application.

For more information see also

- https://help.eclipse.org/2019-12/index.jsp?topic=%2Forg.eclipse.jdt.doc.user%2FgettingStarted%2Fqs-3.htm
- https://help.eclipse.org/2019-12/index.jsp?topic=%2Forg.eclipse.jdt.doc.user%2Freference%2Fref-wizard-java-project.htm

Answer (score 0):

Thanks everyone,

I did not found any .JAVA files in the source so I am sure that they did not pass me the complete source file!

Thanks
Sepide